# Programmatically enable another language

Tags: i18n-l10n

I'm trying to programmatically enable/install another language? (Through install profile).. Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your environment is Drupal [7](/questions/tagged/7) (or [6](/questions/tagged/6) may be OK, too?), you can use [locale_add_language()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21locale.inc/function/locale_add_language/7.x) function (defined in `locale` in the core). For example, if you want to enable French, run `locale_add_language("fr")` and the job's done.

Then, you can check the result via [language_list()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/language_list/7.x) to make sure.